# How do I correctly deploy a .war file to OpenShift?

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, war

I am attempting to deploy my java web application to OpenShift (Tomcat 7). The app runs fine on my local tomcat. I upload the .war file to OpenShift,and put it to webapps location,but I can't reach this app through my web browser,it just show me an empty page.However when I Manually create a file like test.html ,I can get it's content.And I have check the authority,it is correct.
Curious,I don't what is wrong with me.Please help,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you might be trying the wrong url, you should be able to test it at *yourApp-yourDomain.rhcloud.com/yourWARname*.

See [OpenShift Deployment directions](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-deployment-options.html), or see my blog if you are additionally interested in [custom domain or GWT deployment with your WAR on OpenShift](http://www.cellepo.com/2015/10/16/smoke-test-gwt-2-6-starter-webapp-running-on-openshift-tomcat-7-gear/#more-153).

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot.

Comment: @SunnyMarkLiu Great, please upvote my Answer then.  That's how to show your support on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

you can do like that External Sources link :**[Link1](http://shekhargulati.com/2012/11/25/deploy-war-on-tomcat-running-on-openshift/) & 
[Link2](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740)**

You basically have two options to use if you want to deploy applications that have already been compiled into WAR or EAR files onto your OpenShift gear, either add them into your git repository, or scp/sftp them directly to your gear.